# Three.js and React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, three.js

I am a super noob to Three.js trying to get it to work with React..

I was following this medium article
*[Starting with React 16 and Three.js in 5 minutes](https://blog.bitsrc.io/starting-with-react-16-and-three-js-in-5-minutes-3079b8829817)*

I am trying to replicate this example in Three.js:

https://threejs.org/examples/?q=snow#webgl_points_sprites
https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/webgl_points_sprites.html

My codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/clever-sid-r7egd?file=/src/ThreeCanvas.js

I might be wrong, but it seems like it's not loading the snowflake pictures(?). My console.log of sprite1 shows: image: undefined

I have been at it a couple of hours now and all I can get is a black screen...

Answer (score 1):

It must be the way CodeSandbox has its local file structure set up, because if you use the direct URL to the Three.js example images, your demo works as expected:

```
var threeFolder = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mrdoob/three.js/master/examples/textures/sprites/";
var sprite1 = textureLoader.load(threeFolder + "snowflake1.png");
var sprite2 = textureLoader.load(threeFolder + "snowflake2.png");
var sprite3 = textureLoader.load(threeFolder + "snowflake3.png");
var sprite4 = textureLoader.load(threeFolder + "snowflake4.png");
var sprite5 = textureLoader.load(threeFolder + "snowflake5.png");
```

[Click for working demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/charming-kapitsa-l8ooy?file=/src/ThreeCanvas.js:764-1229)

Comment: Wow thanks, it wasn't working in vscode either.. but when I used the direct URL method everything worked.